# Leaflet markers at same geo location (ClusterGroup)

Tags: leaflet, clustering, markers, grouping

I have a map created with leaflet with different markers. Sometimes the markers have the same (1:1) geo position.

I have already tested the great addon clustergroup, but I need the function to be able to spiderfy/open multiple groups. Unfortunately it is apparently not possible to open multiple clustergroups with the addon at the same time so my question is whether there is another way to display markers if they are on exactly the same position.

Comment: You mean Overlapping Marker Spiderfier plugin?

Comment: I have already read about this plugin. Is it possible to open/spiderfy several overlapped groups at the same time with this plugin?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, I just wanted to check which one you are using. How would you separate markers in the same position to different groups? By layer groups? And how would you visually differentiate (and click) groups that are at the same position?